# Move album from iTunes on PC to Macbook wirelessly

Tags: itunes, windows, music

I have just used iTunes to import a CD on my desktop Windows 7 PC.

I'd actually like the CD on my Macbook Pro's (El Capitan) iTunes library; I've been using iTunes' Music Sharing to access it in the past.

How can I "wirelessly import" this CD from my PC's iTunes onto my Macbook's?

The two iTunes libraries use different iTunes accounts.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just do the same thing on the Mac with the CD you did on the PC?

Comment: @user3439894 Yes; I do not have a CD slot in my Macbook, and I do not want to buy apple's USB CD thingy ([here](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MD564ZM/A/apple-usb-superdrive)). I cannot physically connect the macbook to the CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with looking for an iTunes based solution. Instead I would:

- Locate the audio tracks in Windows Explorer.
- Transfer the tracks to your Mac by whatever means you have (direct network connection, Dropbox etc.).
- Import the tracks into iTunes on Mac (e.g. by double-clicking them in Finder).

Comment: Good idea! I used Finder's [connect to server](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18710?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) to see my PC's files, went to `\Users\*\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music` and there were the songs. Then I just dragged the album's folder into iTunes. Thank you!